# Merging of selected lines

Tags: linux

Using the output of the `df -h` command:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol
                        30G  495M   28G   2% /
tmpfs                  28G   18G   11G  64% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   87M  366M  20% /boot
/dev/sda2             200M  256K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol1
                        4.8G  3.8G  778M  84% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol2
                    30G   14G   15G  49% /test_app
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol3
                    16G  2.5G   13G  17% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol4
                    4.8G  4.1G 600M 100% /usr
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol5
                    30G  707M   28G   3% /var
192.5.9.14:/mount1414/
                    16T  2.9T   13T  19% /file14
192.5.9.15:/mount1415/
                    16T  2.9T   13T  20% /file15
```

I would like to format it to:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol  30G  495M   28G   2% /                   
tmpfs                         28G   18G   11G  64% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2                     477M   87M  366M  20% /boot
/dev/sda1                     200M  256K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol1  4.8G  3.8G  778M  84% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol2 30G   14G   15G  49% /opt

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol3 16G  2.5G   13G  17% /test_app

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol4 4.8G  4.1G  600M  100% /usr

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol5 30G  707M   28G   3% /var

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol6 94G  6.4G   83G   8% /var/crash

192.5.9.14:/mount1414/       16T  2.9T   13T  19% /file14

192.5.9.15:/mount1415/       16T  2.9T   13T  20% /file15
```

I would like to detect when `/usr` partition is greater than 90 and clear this partition through a sheduled cron job. I would like to use this command:

```
 df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|/dev/sda' | awk '{print $1 $5}'
```

to find out the partition and partiton size then clear logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more wise to remove older log files instead of all, so maybe you are loking for something like this:

```
find /mnt/log_files -mtime +30 -exec rm  {}\
```

This will delete all files older than 30 days in the mount point `/mnt/log_files`

Comment: i would like to know how to merge the selected lines  so that i can use awk command:                                                                                                            df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|/dev/sda' | awk '{print $1 $5}'                        then i will get an out put as                                                                       /dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol4 4.8G  4.1G  600M  100% /usr